# How to get the each record with some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following data:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
         ID int  
    ,sn varchar(200)
    ,comment varchar(2000)
    ,rownumber int
    )
insert into @temp values(1,'sn1',NULL,1)
insert into @temp values(2,'sn1','aaa',2)
insert into @temp values(3,'sn1','bbb',3)
insert into @temp values(4,'sn1',NULL,4)
insert into @temp values(5,'sn2',NULL,1)
insert into @temp values(6,'sn2',NULL,2)
insert into @temp values(7,'sn2',NULL,3)

select * from @temp
```

And I want to output like this:

```
2   sn1 aaa  2
5   sn2 NULL 1
```

same sn, if comment have value, get this lower rownumber's record. For sn1, have two records with comment value, so here, get the the record with rownumber=2

If comment doesn't have value, get the lower rownumber's record. For sn2, get the record with rownumber=1

May I know how to write this SQL?

Comment: Please format the code as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  I think `row_number()` is the simplest method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sn
                                order by (case when comment is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                         rownumber
                               ) as seqnum
      from @temp t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2e5d0b5590d5ff8c69da4229668b3195) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  from your code, i known the order by case when ..  new syntax. It is good.  thanks again.